# How to load non unique data into primary keys SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to load data from a table with duplicates to a table where the column with duplicates (CountryID) is a primary key. I use this code but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO Countries (CountryID, CountryCode, CountryName)
     SELECT field1,field2,field3 
     FROM african_crises
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                      FROM Countries
                      WHERE (african_crises.field1=Countries.CountryID )
                     )
```

I get this error message:

> Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: Countries.CountryID

Comment: if you have more than one value for field2 or field3 what is the rule to know what field1 to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Countries (CountryID, CountryCode, CountryName)
SELECT field1, min(field2), min(field3)
FROM african_crises
where field1 not in (select CountryID from Countries) <-- this condition is optional
group by field1
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you! I don't understand the logic behind it though. Would you help explain?

Comment: @bluemuse logic here is to select only unique rows from `african_crises` and then insert them, this is how `group by` works